# How do I export views from one organization and import into another

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Is there any way to export views from an organization and then import them into another?

There is a button to fetch the XML of the view, which produces a file with all my info.  This seems like the way to go but how do I re-import it?

We are using the new CRM 2013 update in case in matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are system views they will be exported with the customizations.

If they are private views your best bet might be to use the API.  The entity for User views is called `userquery`.

Comment: Is it possible to export a solution of just the views?  The customizations are already in another solution that has been deployed.
If so, would the views merge with any new ones made on prodution already or would they all be overwritten?

Comment: Solution imports in CRM will overwrite existing customizations, however it will never delete anything.  So if you have views in ORG B that aren't in ORG A and you import customization from ORG A into ORG B nothing will happen to those.

Comment: There isn't a way to just export the views.  If you wanted to do something like that you can do that via the API.  With entity customizations it is all or none when exporting and importing.

Comment: you can't export system views via the API, I tried many times. it is not a supported feature.  yes I can do it with user views, but system views are stubborn little buggers. they just don't budge.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to read your own:

```cs
string fetchXML =
    @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
        <entity name='userquery'>
          <all-attributes />
        </entity>
      </fetch>";
var fetchExpression = new FetchExpression(fetchXML);

var conversionRequest = new FetchXmlToQueryExpressionRequest { FetchXml = fetchXML };
var conversionResponse = (FetchXmlToQueryExpressionResponse)fromService.Execute(conversionRequest);
```

However, it won't show me anyone else's -- yes, I have admin security.

Comment: <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='userquery'>
    <all-attributes />
  </entity>
</fetch>